# MySQL workbench extended properties?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mysql-workbench

I've been working for a while with SQL Server and I use Extended Properties to tag databases, tables and columns. Most of the time an item can have more than one Extended Properties.

For example, a column could have a property DisplayName and Version that are used by a web client that walk the database.

For reasons beyond my control, I must migrate my SQL server database to MySQL.

**The thing is that the concept of Extented Properties doesn't seem to exist with MySQL Workbench.
Is there an equivalent? If not, what do you guys do to compensate the lack of this feature?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For reasons beyond my control, I must migrate my SQL server database to MySQL.

Good luck with that... (If it's about the money, try to convince your boss to use PostgreSQL instead.)

More seriously: whichever database you're using has a system catalog somewhere. Adding properties and tags are nothing more than a few entries to that catalog.

If you were using PostgreSQL, these tables would be in the pg_catalog schema. In so far as MySQL is concerned, the tables are in the information_schema:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html

To add extra properties, tags, etc. you can always add tables (in your own shema/database) and insert that meta data as needed. The syntax won't be fancy SQL constructs, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about it, creating my own extended properties table seems the way to go. I'll mark this as answered, but if someone has other suggestions, feel free to post them.
Thanks Denis!